# I can neither remove nor reopen my question

Tags: support, reopen-closed

I asked a question [Spring @Autowired violates DRY principle. What can be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964732/spring-autowired-violates-dry-principle-what-can-be-done)

And it was put on hold because its original version contained a word library. I removed that word a week ago and requested to reopen but it didn't work. So I decided to delete a question but I can't because there is an answer. This answer isn't an answer actually. It suggests to do something that I said in the question I wouldn't like to do. But I don't believe that if I mark it as not an answer it would be deleted and I can finally delete my question.

Also I've found an answer to the question but can't post it. And if I create another question in order to answer it, it will be duplicate and against the rules.

I think that this behavior of SO (when you can nothing to do with your question) is wrong.

Comment: I think the close reason is indeed not valid anymore, I cast a reopen vote.

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Comment: Thanks. Should I delete this post?

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk No, don't delete this post, as it may be useful to others readers in the future. You can add a self-answer that your post has been reopened and your problem has been solved this way. Then, 24 hours after you posted your self-answer, you can accept it and everything is good.